# Remove default favicon on localhost

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-cache, favicon

I developed a website with a favicon and now every time I access localhost (for my other projects), I get that same favicon showing up. I'm on OSX, using Chrome. I tried clearing the cache; it flashed to the default unknown favicon first, then immediately grabbed the website one (that I don't want). Anyone know where to find that favicon so I can remove it? None of my other browsers have this problem (Firefox, Safari).

Comment: Are you using an actual release version of Chrome or some buggy testing alpha/beta/canary build?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Visited `http://localhost` after setting up `/favicon.ico` on the site, it was displayed. Deleted favicon file, cleared cache and restarted Chrome: It's gone.

Comment: I am using an actual release of Chrome. Also- I deleted the entire project directory where that favicon is stored, cleared my cache in Chrome and restarted the browser and it still is showing up on localhost. Any other advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this, I went into Preferences, Under the Hood, Clear Browsing Data, and selected all the options with "from the beginning of time" as the date reference. I was hoping to not have to do this and lose all my browsing history/data, but it worked.

Comment: For me it was specifically the "Browsing history" option that did it.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac, delete: `${user.home}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons`

For Windows: go to `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and delete `favicons` and `favicons-journal` files

Source: http://www.nullalo.com/en/how-to-delete-google-chrome-favicon-cache/ [see #3 in the link]

I find this to be the least intrusive method since it does not delete your browser history or anything else as suggested in the other solutions.

Comment: Great! You answer helped me to extract old favicon of some site from Chrome storage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64263576/4928642.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course always make an empty PNG file and set it as the favicon in an `index.html` page so the cache is overwritten:

```
<html><head><link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png' /></head></html>
```

The default icon is still not there :( but it's a way to avoid deleting all your history.

Comment: If you're a stickler meeseeks you can set it to a lookalike of the default: http://static.dealer.com/v8/global/images/site-favicon-default.ico